# Condition in IEquatable<T>.Equals

Tags: c#, linq, comparison

I have implemented `IEquatable<T>` to compare objects in two lists however i want to do it conditionally like this:

```
public bool Equals(CustomerType other)
{

    if (this.Zipcode == "11111" || this.Zipcode == "22222" || this.Zipcode== "33333")
       {
          return this.FirstName.Equals(other.FirstName) && this.LastName.Equals(other.LastName) && this.MiddleName.Equals(other.MiddleName);
       }
       else
       {
          return this.FirstName.Equals(other.FirstName);
       }
}
```

Something is wrong here and it never goes to else condition. Can someone please tell me where am i going wrong?

--Usage--

var v = listA.Except(listB).ToList();

--GetHashCode implementation--

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {

            int hash = 17;         
            hash = hash * 23 + this.intField1.GetHashCode();         
            hash = hash * 23 + this.intField2.GetHashCode();         
            hash = hash * 23 + this.stringField3.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.doubleField4.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.doubleField5.GetHashCode();         

            return hash;
        }
    }
```

--Equals--

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) return base.Equals(obj);
        if (obj is CustomerType ) 
        { 
            return this.Equals((CustomerType)obj); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
```

--Example--

ListA has 2 Customers:

Cust1:
FirstName - "A"
LastName - "Z"
MiddleName - "Y"
ZipCode - "11111"

Cust2:
FirstName - "B"
LastName - "X"
MiddleName - "W"
ZipCode - "44444"

ListB has 2 Customers:

Cust1:
FirstName - "A"
LastName - "Z"
MiddleName - "Y"
ZipCode - "11111"

Cust2:
FirstName - "B"
LastName - "G"
MiddleName - "G"
ZipCode - "44444"

Here when i say ListA.Except(ListB), it shud compare CustA with FirstName, MiddleName, LastName because it belongs to Zipcode 11111 and CustB with only FirstName and the same applies when i say ListB.Except(ListA). What is happeing in current Equals implementation is that it works fine with ListA.Except(ListB) but when i say ListB.Except(ListA), it compares FirstName, LastName and Middlename for CustB.

Comment: Can we see the code that actually uses this?  I have a suspicion about what the problem is, but would like to verify by seeing how you are using it.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje - Edited the code usage

Comment: Did you override the normal equals too?

Comment: Yes. I did. Edited the question with the implementation.

Comment: Now it returns the list with customers whose zipcode is not 11111 or 22222 or 33333. Its not comparing FirstName only

Comment: You still haven't fixed your symmetry problem. I assume you only want to use `FirstName` comparison if *both* sides have a zip code that's not in the list. Currently it's enough if the left side has such a zip code.

Comment: Thats correct. How do i fix that? Can you please edit the question and place Equals method at the end of the question for me to understand how do i fix it? I dont know what am i doing wrong there.

Comment: First you need to specify how you want to handle entries with different zip codes.

Comment: i think i see what you are saying. var v = listA.Except(listB).ToList(); works fine and returns nothing but var w = listB.Except(listA).ToList(); returns objects bcz "other" becomes "this" here. No idea how do i fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the symmetry of your equals and hashcode functions and based on what you said in the comments on another answer, I believe this is the implementation you need:

```
public bool Equals(CustomerType other)
{

    if ((this.Zipcode == "11111" || this.Zipcode == "22222" || this.Zipcode== "33333") &&
        (other.Zipcode == "11111" || other.Zipcode == "22222" || other.Zipcode== "33333"))
       {
          return this.FirstName.Equals(other.FirstName) && 
                 this.LastName.Equals(other.LastName) && 
                 this.MiddleName.Equals(other.MiddleName);
       }
       else
       {
          return this.FirstName.Equals(other.FirstName);
       }
}
```

And for GetHashCode:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (this.Zipcode == "11111" || this.Zipcode == "22222" || this.Zipcode== "33333")
    {
        return FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ LastName.GetHashCode() ^ MiddleName.GetHashCode();
    }
    else
    {
        return FirstName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

ETA - to expand a bit - it appears your implementation simply isn't consistent with the definition of equality.

Making a slightly different assumption (that customer B and A have the same first name), ask yourself the following questions:

1. Is Customer A equal to Customer B?  By your code, the answer is no.
2. Is Customer B equal to Customer A?  By your code, the answer is yes.

When comparing Customer A to Customer B, your implementation will use first, last & middle names.  But when comparing Customer B to Customer A, your implementation will only use first name.  This violates the [fundamental definition of equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28mathematics%29):

> The symmetric property states:
>
> ```
> * For any quantities a and b, if a = b, then b = a.
> ```

Any built in functions that rely on your `Equals` method will assume that its implementation is consistent with the definition of equality.  Since your implementation is not, you are violating that assumption and therefore getting inconsistent results.

Comment: `Xor`ing multiple properties in `GetHashCode` is usually a bad idea, since then the hash is invariant under commutation of those properties. So collisions get more likely. It's probably no problem in this case, but I'd generally avoid it.

Comment: And you should add `null` handling to your `Equals`.

Comment: @Code - both good points, left out the null handling for clarity (and since he didn't have it in his, so figured it was uneccessary in his case)

Comment: I have null check in Equals. I just didnt put it in here. Your answer is very helpful. Now i understand what you guys meant by "symmetry of your Equals". Sorry no CS or Engineering background. Just one question tho. If i put other.Zipcode first in the equals, it gives me wrong results. Does that order matter?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you did't implement `GetHashCode()` correctly. Whenever you override `Equals` you must override `GetHashCode()` so they are consistent.

The condition is that if for two objects `o1.Equals(o2)` returns true then the results of `GetHashCode` must be the same.

Since `Except` uses a hashset internally the implementation of  `GetHashCode()` is relevant here. Without a hashset it's complexity would grow from O(n) to O(n^2) which is clearly undesirable.

In addition to that `Equals` should be symmetrical and yours isn't.

---

Looking into your `GetHashCode()` function it is clearly wrong. It takes fields into account that `Equals` doesn't.

Whenever your code goes into the `then` part of the `if` it may take `FirstName`, `LastName` and `MiddleName` into account. When your code goes into the `else` part it may only take `FirstName` into account for `GetHashCode()`.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
    if (this.Zipcode == "11111" || this.Zipcode == "22222" || this.Zipcode== "33333")
    {
        return FirstName.GetHashCode()*529+
               LastName.GetHashCode()*23+
               MiddleName.GetHashCode();
    }
    else
    {
        return FirstName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

But even with this implementation of `GetHashCode()` you'll still should fix the symmetry of your `Equals`

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I have implemented GethashCode. Let me put the implementation in the question detail

Comment: +1 for mentioning the symmetry issue.  Even if GetHashCode is implemented consistently, I suspect this may be the issue.

Comment: what fields should i include in GetHashCode? Only those which i need to compare?

Comment: Obiously only those you compare. Else the consistency condition is violated when you have two objects that are identical in the compared fields but differ in other hashed fields.

Comment: no idea what you mean by " symmetry of your Equals". What is wrong with it? Can you please explain and suggest what should i fix there?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I disagree. The hash code can use less or more fields, or even just return a constant. It do do agree, however, that above all else it *must* return consistent values.

Comment: i implemented the GetHashCode your way but now it returns entire list as "non matched".

Comment: Just a constant or less fields is fine(just sometimes decreases the hash quality). But can you show an example where *more* fields are used in the hash than in equals without breaking the contract?

Comment: Your symmetry problem is that if the zip codes are different that it can happen that `a.Equals(b)` is different from `b.Equals(a)`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good catch "If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value."

Comment: +1 I'd put more emphasis on the equals symmetry because it should be critical, if not for this immediate problem.

Comment: @Asdfg - by symmetry we mean that if `a == b` is true then `b == a` should also be true.  Similarly if `a != b` then `b !=a`.  With your implementation, that is not the case which means it violates the mathematical definition of equality.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje - What do i need to do to change the implementation of Equals to make it correct? Is it not possible to do so? Are you saying that i cannot do conditional comparison here?

Comment: @Asdfg - That depends on what makes two CustomerType objects equal.  From the way you implemented it, it's not entirely clear what you were intending.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje - I have two lists with CustomerType objects in them. I need to compare them to find out missing or mismatch customers. I have 3 fields to compare here i.e. FirstName, MiddleName, LastName. But if customer's zipcode is 11111 or 22222 or 33333 then that customer object should be compared only with FirstName.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: I have added an example in the question. Please check.

Comment: @Asdfg - I've added an answer that should solve your problem and clarify exactly where things went wrong with your existing code.